# Slick Carousel Not Initializing Intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jstl, slick.js

I'm having a bit of a rough time with my [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel. I have a feed of articles on a website being pulled in through an API which displays each article within its own slide. I'm populating the slides using a combination of Bootstrap and JSTL tags.

The issue I'm having seems intermittent, sometimes it works and other times it doesn't which makes me hesitant to deploy it into production. Here is what it's doing when it doesn't work:

[image: It should not be doing this]

And here is what it's supposed to do (and does on occasion):

[image: It should be doing this]

I'm not quite sure what seems to be the problem here, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the content being loaded after the carousel has been initialized which is causing intermittent issues with it.

Here is the code I'm using *(Please note I've removed a number of variables and unnecessary code from this so the JSTL tags might not make sense)*:

```
<div class="carousel-article ">

        <c:forEach var="element" items="${listContent.items}" begin="${beginIndex}" end="${endIndex}" varStatus="status">

                <article>
                    <header>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <c:if test="${not empty promoImage}">
                                    <a href="${element.canonical_url}">
                                      <img data-lazy="${formatUrl}"
                                      alt="${promoImage.caption}" />
                                    </a>
                                </c:if>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <figure>
                                    <a href="${element.canonical_url}">
                                         <h4>${element.headline}</h4>
                                    </a>
                                  </div>
                                </c:if>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                </header>
            </article>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
(function($, window) {
  $('.carousel-article').slick({
    arrows: true,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  })(jQuery, window);
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console when it fails?

Comment: @Red2678 Nothing sadly.

Comment: @Red2678 Although I can say if I increase the amount of data being populated in the slide to say 10 instead of 5 it fails more frequently. This leads me to believe it's some sort of loading issue.

Comment: @BalusC The problem is intermittent using JSP, it doesn't always seem to occur. I'm not sure I understand what you want me to demonstrate.

Comment: The issue does not occur if I'm not using JSP/JSTL. I don't know if it's because it's pulling dynamic content or not but I can't reproduce the issue with plain HTML.

Comment: @JamesIves Were you able to solve the issue, if yes, please let us know.